# Adjointiness, Poisson bracket and KdV equation

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

Consider this (I am only having issues with the proof, the example is added as context and definitions)

> Example (Showing that KdV equation is bi-Hamiltonian) We can write the KdV equation in Hamiltonian form by
> $$
> \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\mathcal{J}_1 \delta H_1, \quad \mathcal{J}_1=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \quad H_1[u]=\int \frac{1}{2} u_x^2+u^3 \mathrm{~d} x .
> $$
> We can check that this says
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} & =\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial u}-D_x\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial u_x}\right)\right)\left(\frac{1}{2} u_x^2+u^3\right) \\
> & =6 u u_x-u_{x x x}
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> and this is the $\mathrm{KdV}$ equation.
> We can also write it as
> $$
> \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\mathcal{J}_0 \delta H_0, \quad \mathcal{J}_0=-\frac{\partial^3}{\partial x^3}+4 u \partial_x+2 u_x, \quad H_0[u]=\int \frac{1}{2} u^2 \mathrm{~d} x .
> $$
> So $\mathrm{KdV}$ is bi-Hamiltonian. We then know that
> $$
> \mathcal{J}_1 \delta H_1=\mathcal{J}_0 \delta H_0
> $$
> We define a sequence of Hamiltonians $\left\{H_n\right\}_{n \geq 0}$ via
> $$
> \mathcal{J}_1 \delta H_{n+1}=\mathcal{J}_0 \delta H_n
> $$
> We will assume that we can always solve for $H_{n+1}$ given $H_n$. This can be proven, but we shall not. We then have the miraculous result.

> Theorem 4.2
> Suppose a system is bi-Hamiltonian via $\left(\mathcal{J}_0, H_0\right)$ and $\left(\mathcal{J}_1, H_1\right)$. It is a fact that we can find a sequence $\left\{H_n\right\}_{n \geq 0}$ such that
> $$
> \mathcal{J}_1 \delta H_{n+1}=\mathcal{J}_0 \delta H_n
> $$
> Under these definitions, $\left\{H_n\right\}$ are all first integrals of the system and are in involution, i.e.
> $$
> \left\{H_n, H_m\right\}=0
> $$
> for all $n, m \geq 0$, where the Poisson bracket is taken with respect to $\mathcal{J}_1$.

> Proof. We notice the following interesting fact: for $m \geq 1$, we have
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> \left\{H_n, H_m\right\} & :=\left\langle\delta H_n, \mathcal{J}_1 \delta H_m\right\rangle \\
> & =\left\langle\delta H_n, \mathcal{J}_0 \delta H_{m-1}\right\rangle \\
> & =-\left\langle\mathcal{J}_0 \delta H_n, \delta H_{m-1}\right\rangle \\
> & =-\left\langle\mathcal{J}_1 \delta H_{n+1}, \delta H_{m-1}\right\rangle \\
> & =\left\langle\delta H_{n+1}, \mathcal{J}_1 \delta H_{m-1}\right\rangle \\
> & =\left\{H_{n+1}, H_{m-1}\right\} .
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> (due fact)
> Iterating this many times, we find that for any $n, m$, we have
> $$
> \left\{H_n, H_m\right\}=\left\{H_m, H_n\right\} .
> $$
> Then by antisymmetry, they must both vanish. So done.

I am having some issues with the step

$$ <\delta H_n ,\mathcal{J}_0 \delta H_{m-1} > = - < \mathcal{J}_0 \delta H_n , \delta H_{m-1} >.
$$
I can see why this could be true for $\mathcal{J_1}$, because of integration by parts, but I don't think you can do this here. I should also mention that
$$
< f,g > = \int_{\mathbb{R} }^{} f g \, \mathrm{d}x. 
$$

Does anybody know what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integration by parts is another way of saying that $\mathcal J_1=\partial_x$ is anti-symmetric (or skew-adjoint, if you like) with respect to the scalar product of $L^2$. It is not difficult to see that $\mathcal J_0$ is anti-symmetric using integration by parts:

$$ \langle w,\mathcal J_0v\rangle=\int w(-v_{xxx}+4uv_x+2u_xv)=\int w(-v_{xxx}+4(uv)_x-2u_xv)= $$
$$ =-\int -w_{xxx}v+4uvw_x+2u_xvw =-\int v(w_{xxx}+4uw_x+2u_xw)=-\langle \mathcal J_0 w,v\rangle. $$

I omitted the $dx$ and $\mathbb R$ for simplicity of notation.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. Here are we actually restricted to the $L^2$ functions with compact support that are infinitely differentiable? As in why can we do what we did?

Comment: I am not sure. All of this is generally very formal, and making it rigorous is not necessarily desirable. If you want to make it rigorous, then it is enough to assume that $u,v,w\in H^3(\mathbb R)$. The problem is that the KdV equation does not preserve the space of compactly supported fuctions, so I am not sure if assuming compact support is what you want. Of course, with such an assumption, the above computation is rigorous.